Meaning of 出来 in 妥協することは出来かねます。
Full sentence: 折角ですが、これ以上妥協することは出来かねます。
What does 出来 mean here? Is this a combination of the verbs 出来る and かねます or is 出来 a noun here?

でき is the masu-stem of verb できる, followed by かねる which means

４ 他の動詞の連用形に付いて用いる。
㋐…しようとして、できない。…することがむずかしい。「納得し—・ねる」「何とも言い—・ねる」

So, for example, 納得しかねる=unable to understand/accept.
I guess, you are asking because できる already means can and appending かねる=unable looks kind of redundant. But, after all, かねる is just a different word from できる, so literally, as per the above definition, it is like hard to be able (to do something).
In practice, できかねる means the same thing as できない, but sounds somewhat softer (though it is not a keigo).

It sounds similar to the difference in English between "It's hard for me to ~" and "I cannot ~".

Is this 兼ねる  somehow related to 難い?

@KarlKnechtel Most likely no. Old Japanese e₂ is often fusion of a + i, so kane₂- is probably from kana - i, while 難{かた}い is from 堅{かた}い from *kata.

妥協しかねる would have been just fine.
